# Adding custom handlers to WSO2 ESB proxy service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to add custom handlers to a proxy service created in wso2 esb. Using handler I want to

1. Intercept the call to the proxy service
2. Perform some operation and set values to the context

axis2.xml seems to be a place to achieve this but it seems a common configuration for all the proxy services. What if I want to use custom validation handlers for specific proxy services?

Answer (score 1):

you can write a custom esb mediator for this purpose. By extending AbstractMediator, you can write your own mediator class where you have access to messageContext. Then you can place this mediator in your proxy service. Some of the articles which may helpful to you.

[1]http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-write-custom-mediator-wso2-esb.html

[2]http://wso2.com/library/2898

[3]http://maninda.blogspot.com/2012/11/writing-custom-mediator-for-wso2-esb.html

Comment: Lakmali, thanks for your response. The custom mediator comes into effect in the sequences between proxy and the endpoint. I was looking for something to intercept the code before reaching the proxy itself and have access to the message context there (like an in handler for a web service)

Answer (score 0):

You can see how a handler is added to ESB in [1]

https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/tag/how-easily-engage-the-security-for-rest-services-with-wso2-esb/